# Get keys of activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an active record to which I want to collect its keys in a seperate array

So if my `@item.first` has

```
item.a = 1
item.b = 2
item.c = 3
```

I want to collect an array like `[a => 1, b => 2, c => 3]`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `attributes`:

```
@item.first.attributes
```

And to select specific attributes you can filter with `select` as:

```
@item.first.attributes.select { |key| ['a', 'b', 'c'].include?(key) }
```

Comment: And how do I push them back into a new array? Because attrs << [key => val] gives them back with brackets. I'd like to use them in other loops as key, value on screen. (`<% attrs.each do |k, v| %> <%= k.id %> <% end %>`)

Comment: @CaptainCarl, I'm not sure I understand your comment clearly.  If you wanted to filter out the results and build a new array from the filtered results wouldn't doing a `Item.select('a, b, c').where(...)` be a better?  Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: No, I just want some of the keys to be seperated for easy use later on . So `activerecord.a = 1` can be calles as `<%= activerecord.a %>`(outputs 1). I want that same structure for my new array. `<%= newarray.a %>` (outputs 1)

Comment: Ah, got it. needed `attrs = Hash.new` than `attrs[key] = val`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using as_json read this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json